# NLog double logging - how to find the problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

There are multiple articles on SO and the rest of the internet on this, but I think I've followed all of the all the advice and recommendations, and I'm still getting double logs, so clearly I'm doing something else wrong here.

I have a .NET Core web app with the following `rules` section in my nlog.config:

```
  <rules>
    <logger name="MyApp.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fileSystem,database" final="true"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="database" final="true"/>
  </rules>
```

In my Startup.ConfigureServices method, I have a line:

```
services.AddLogging();
```

and in the Startup.Configure method, I have a link to a helper method like so:

```
app.StartLogging(Configuration);
```

This helper method is written like so:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder StartLogging(this IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration config)
{
    var loggerFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["appDbConnectionString"] = config["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationContext"];
    return app;
}
```

...and that's it.  There's no more mentions of NLog anywhere else in this project.  Yet, I'm still getting double log entries for info.  Why? And how can I detect that there are multiple NLog loggers running on my `ILoggerFactory`?

Comment: If `UseNLog` in Program.cs is not possible (See  https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs ). Then you can do this in Startup.cs: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2859#issuecomment-415865357

Comment: I assume you've looked at this already.  But it sounds like you're desperate for help, so I'm going to ask, have you followed the Best Practices documentation here? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: I found the best practices to be far from standard best practices.  Creating static loggers and tightly coupling to a library like NLog don't really fit in my definition of "best practices", so I deliberately did not do it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I agree with you. But it would be a piece of cake to write an abstract interface class that abstracts the NLog static calls away from your system code. I wasn't trying to indicate you should do exactly what they're doing.  I just see that nobody else responded yet and your problem is very peculiar.  So I was suggesting maybe there's something different in the recommended starting guidelines versus the steps you took.  Trying to help. :D

Comment: I appreciate it; still, it has a smell that I'd like to avoid.  Right now, this is annoying, not critical, so I'd prefer to find an answer that doesn't make me regret the code I just wrote. :P

Comment: Have you checked the internal log? (on trace level) - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adjusting your rules. All three of your rules tell NLog to write to the database; I'm guessing two of the rules are getting picked up for certain calls to the logger. I was getting double entries in my database table with a similar rules configuration. I removed a 'logger name="*"' rule that wrote to the database and the double entries stopped.

Answer (score 1):

NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.8.6 [changes registration of NLog Logging Provider](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/485), so one is now allowed to call both `AddNLog` and `UseNLog` without experiencing double logging.

NLog 5.0 implements [validation of incorrect duplicate target configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4354), so one will not experience double logging when using incorrect NLog configuration.